# PHP Search Not Working on Second Parameter

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have tried multiple variations of this code and none seem to work properly. I want my search to look for the variable in both busname OR busdba columns and return result. The current code only returns if you type in a correct busname, but not busdba which is weird to me. Here is code:

```
if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
   $q = $_GET["term"];
   if (!$q) return;
   $return_arr = array();
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM busclients WHERE busdba OR busname LIKE '$q%'")or die(mysql_error());

                while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $busname = $result['busname'] . ", " . $result['busdba'];
                    if(isset($busname)){

                        $description['id'] = 'viewbusiness.php?id=' . $result['ID'];
                    $description['value'] = $busname ;
                    array_push($return_arr,$description);
                    }

                }

echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
```

Comment: your syntax is invalid `WHERE busdba OR busname LIKE` = `WHERE busdba is_what? OR busname LIKE` - surely `mysql_error()` must've thrown you something.

Comment: Use _PDO_ or _MySQLi_, the driver you're using is deprecated. Also use _prepared statements_. Good luck g!

Comment: Read the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong. Please correct it

```
"SELECT * FROM busclients WHERE busdba LIKE '$q%' OR busname LIKE '$q%'"
```

Comment: Boom thank you very much!

Comment: great! But, it will be good if go through basics of MYSQL. That will help you in future. Also, please vote for my answer if it helped you.